# Publishing JSON output from a web api to Google Big Query results in data being written to a failed records table

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Google Pub Sub to publish the JSON output of a web API to a specific topic. I am then using a google dataflow template. The exact template I am using is PUBSUB to BIGQUERY which moves the data from pubsub into a specific table I have defined. When the task runs all the data moves to a failed table insert instead of writing successful records. I am thinking it has to be a problem with how the messages are encoded but I have tried multiple things with no avail. My python code is listed below:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from sodapy import Socrata
import json
from io import StringIO
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import time
import datetime
import urllib
import urllib.request
import argparse
import base64

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
# change project to your Project ID
project="xxxx"
# change topic to your PubSub topic name
topic="xxxx"


res = urllib.request.urlopen('https:/myurl.com/test.json')
res_body = res.read()
traffic=json.loads(res_body)
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topicName = 'projects/' + project + '/topics/' + topic
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project,topic)
for key in traffic:
        publisher.publish(topicName,str.encode(str(key)))
        print(key.items())
```

Comment: what error are you seeing? Is it python who's throwing the exception?

Comment: No its not python throwing the error. In the google dataflow template there is a Write failed records section when the records do not match the BQ table. This is where all records are getting written too. However, the fields should match when I looked at the output so I am thinkign the problem is with the encoding or something I am missing in the python code above.